# React, two divs on top of each other, why?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am a student. I have two form elements which are positioned on top of each other, on the page. I want them to be placed side-by-side.

I have no idea why they are doing this. I have commented out all of the css but they are still on top of each other, and both seem to be confined to the middle of the screen. I originally set one form element to be pinned to the middle of the screen, but now I need a second form to sit next to the first form.

I don't know how it's possible that I could comment out all of the CSS but still essentially all of the styling and all of the positioning remains.

Here is code which I believe pertains to the problem. I have other components and other CSS pages, but I've commented out ALL of the CSS pages and the divs still lie on top of each other.

```
//Login.js

import './Login.css'
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Login({ setUser, setIsAuthenticated, setUserWelcome }) {    
    
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState([])
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [signupErrors, setSignupErrors] = useState([])
    const [passwordConfirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState("");

    // login submit
    // login submit
    // login submit
    const loginOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const user = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                res.json()
                .then(user => {
                    setUser(user)
                    setIsAuthenticated(true)
                    // setUserWelcome(user.message)
                    // console.log(user.message)
                    navigate('/about')
                })
            } else {
                    res.json()
                    .then(json => setLoginError(json.error))
                }
            })
        }

    // signup submit
    // signup submit
    // signup submit
    function signupOnSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        setSignupErrors([])
        const user = {
            name: name,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password_confirmation: passwordConfirmation
        }
        fetch('/users', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body:JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                res.json()
                .then(user => {
                    setUser(user)
                    setIsAuthenticated(true)
                    // setMessage201(user.message)
                })
            } else {
                res.json()
                .then(json => setSignupErrors(Object.entries(json.error))
                )}
        })
    }



    return (
        <>
        <div className="main-horizontal-container" >
            {/* login form */}
            {/* login form */}
            {/* login form */}            

            <form onSubmit={loginOnSubmit} className="form">
                <div className="container1">
                    <div className="container4">
                        <p></p>
                    <h3 className="login-h3">Login</h3>
                    <Link to='/signup'><h3 className="login-h3">Signup</h3></Link>

                    </div>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Username" 
                        name="uname" 
                        />
                    <input 
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Password" 
                        name="pwd" 
                        />
                    <div className="container2">
                        <button className="button1" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container3">
                    {loginError ? <div>{loginError}</div> : null}
                </div>
            </form>
            
            {/* signup form */}
            {/* signup form */}
            {/* signup form */}
                          
            <form onSubmit={signupOnSubmit} className="form">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="name"
                        placeholder="name"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        placeholder="username" 
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    <input 
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="password" 
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    <input 
                        type="password"
                        id="password_confirmation"
                        placeholder="confirm password" 
                        value={passwordConfirmation}
                        onChange={(e) => setPasswordConfirmation(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    <button 
                        type="submit">Sign up
                    </button>
            </form>
            
            { signupErrors ? signupErrors.map(e => <div key={e}>{e[0]+' : ' + e[1]}</div>) : null}
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

```
// login.css

body {
    background-color:rgb(33, 33, 34);
}

.form {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
}
/* already a member? */
.login-h3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* form inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 4px 85px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgba(115, 82, 122, 0.486);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(33, 33, 34);
    color:rgba(175, 149, 35, 0.836);
    font-size: 18px;
}
input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: 1px solid rgba(115, 82, 122, 0.938);
}
/* for placeholder text in login form */
::placeholder {
    color: rgba(115, 82, 122, 0.938);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(51, 47, 50);
    color: rgba(115, 82, 122, 1);
    /* height of button/width of button */
    padding: 10px 30px;
    /* spacing from "password"/spacing between buttons */
    margin: 20px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
/* for rounded corners on buttons */
button {border-radius: 12px;}
/* Add a hover effect for buttons */
button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* for login inputs */
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100hv;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
/* for login/forgot buttons */
.container2 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* for login error message */
.container3 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* for div containing "Login/Signup" */
.container4 {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    gap: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* for main flex container which holds login form/signup form */
.main-horizontal-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
}
```

```
// index.css

body {
  background-color:rgb(33, 33, 34);
  color: rgb(139, 56, 139);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100hv;
  margin: 0;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: make an example in codesandbox